# Multiple Meta_values

Tags: meta-value

As you an see I use a `get_pages()` function and it all works fine.

```
$city_ids = get_pages(array("hierarchical" => 0, "sort_column" => "menu_order", "sort_order" => "desc", "meta_key" => "page_type", "meta_value" => 1));
```

But now I want multiple meta_values.

I tried things like:

```
"meta_value" => 1,3
"meta_value" => 1 AND 3
```

But they both don't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters ?

Comment: @kraftner I tried it. But I can't get it to work. I get problems with my WordPress Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array( 
    "numberposts" => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'page', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
    'relation' => 'OR', 
        array( 
            'key' => 'page_type', 
            'value' => 1, 
            'compare' => '=' 
        ), 
        array( 
            'key' => 'page_type', 
            'value' => 3, 
            'compare' => '=' 
        ) 
    ) 
); 

$city_ids = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: That sadly does not work. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: What data is stored as a value for the key you are referring to?

Comment: Ah, wait.. you need to use get_posts instead of get_pages. 

NOTE: This function will currently not retrieve pages using the 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' parameters in the $args array as described below. Until this is fixed in the WordPress codebase, you may want to use get_posts() instead.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I don't think I can do that. On the same website we use this method a lot. Just not with two meta values. There is my confussion.

Comment: Well, according to the wordpress codex, you can't get pages using meta_key & meta_value. You must replace it with get_posts, both are almost the same function. Only some arguments will need to be replaced.

Comment: Sorry, ignore me.. use `meta_query`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Haha thanks! But then again. I tried that. Got loads of results I don

Comment: I don't want* Sorry. Hit enter by accident

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46922/discussion-between-steve-north-and-tristan-de-jager).